# How to write the difference between two files into a file

Tags: diff, vimdiff

Saying that I have two files: `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

The content of `a.txt`:

```
hello world
```

The content of `b.txt`:

```
hello world
something else
```

Of course I can use `vimdiff` to check their difference, I can make sure that `a.txt` is a subset of `b.txt`, which means that `b.txt` must contain all of lines existing in `a.txt` (just like the example above).

My question is how to record lines which exists in `b.txt` but doesn't exist in `a.txt` into a file?

Comment: possible duplicate 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114877/how-to-know-if-a-text-file-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: @WissamRoujoulah  You see, I don't need to check if `a.txt` is a subset of `b.txt`. I've already known that `a.txt` is a subset of `b.txt`. My question is how to print the difference into a file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
comm -1 -3 a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

The `-1` excludes lines that are only in `a.txt`, and the `-3` excludes lines that are in both.  Thus only the lines exclusively in `b.txt` are output (see `man comm` or `comm --help` for details).  The output is redirected to `c.txt`

If you want the difference between the two files, use `diff` rather than `comm`.  e.g.

```
diff -u a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

Comment: +1. `comm` looks like a very handy command during file comparison. But `diff -u` is giving a bunch of other information as well.

Comment: The extra information from `diff` is context and instructions (e.g. `- ` to delete a line, `+ ` to add a line) that allow `b.txt` to be reconstructed from `a.txt` and `c.txt` - i.e. `c.txt` is a patch file, understood by the `patch` program.   Also simple enough for people to easily understand.  BTW, `diff` has several different output styles, `-u` is the "unified diff" format.  There are also various specialised version of diff - e.g. to do side-by-side comparisons, or compare 3 files at once, or find word differences within a line.  `colordiff` is also handy for colourising diff output.

Comment: If the `a.txt` and `b.txt` files are not sorted you will get a warning. To avoid the warning and the sorting use the `--nocheck-order` flag.

Answer (score 6):

If you dont care for subset, you can use just

```
diff a.txt b.txt|grep ">"|cut -c 3- > foo.txt
```

.

```
$ cat a.txt
hello world
$ cat b.txt
hello world
something else
$ diff a.txt b.txt|grep ">"|cut -c 3- > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
something else
```

Answer (score 1):

**Limitation**: this is not a real file diff, more like a set of the lines diff (but you may need exactly this).

All differences between `a.txt` and `b.txt`:

```
sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -u > c.txt
```

Lines which missing from `a.txt` (ignoring lines which missing from `b.txt`):

```
sort a.txt a.txt b.txt | uniq -u > c.txt
```

Explanation: after `cat` and `sort` the 2 files together you have the subset lines duplicated, `uniq -u` shows only the uniq lines, those are the lines which are only present in one of the file. Duplicating one of the input (`a.txt` above) suppresses all the lines exist in that file on the output.

Duplication in any of the files ruins the output of the commands above, if you have duplicates in your files you have to remove those first and run the commands above on the newly created files:

```
sort a.txt | uniq | aa.txt
sort b.txt | uniq | bb.txt
```

You can check the result, this 2 command should give you the same checksum:

```
sort b.txt c.txt | uniq | sha256sum
sort a.txt c.txt | uniq | sha256sum
```

If one of the file is a superset of the other (so it has all lines of the other plus (maybe) more) then you can simplify a bit. Like in your example the `b.txt` is the superset, so this 2 commands should give you the same checksum too:

```
sort b.txt | sha256sum
sort a.txt c.txt | sha256sum
```

Answer (score -2):

b.txt - a.txt :
`sort a.txt a.txt b.txt | uniq -u > foo.txt`

Comment: welcomme to U&L, would you care to explain a little ? specialu why 2 instance of `a.txt` ?

Comment: This doesn’t preserve the order of lines in `b.txt`, and will remove any lines which are repeated in `b.txt` even if they aren’t present in `a.txt`.