# Using pcregrep to search for exact matches of multiline string

Tags: pcregrep

I am trying to search a directory using `pcregrep`. I want to search using a long, multi-line string. Basically, I am trying to look through multiple code bases for plagiarism. So I want to be able copy/paste a code block from some code, and then search a directory for any exact matches.

The problem I'm having is that when I use `pcregrep` with the `-M` option (`pcregrep -M`), it appears to treat each line break as a separate pattern.

So, when I take a code block that I know is unique to one file, I may still get multiple responses because some individual lines may be used elsewhere.

Here is what I am using:
`pcregrep -FlMr "long, multi-line string" /directory/to/search/`

What can I do to make sure that it will only return exact matches?

Comment: It's the `-F` option that causes this behavior I think (*"Interpret  each  data-matching pattern as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, instead of as a regular expression."*). Whether you can safely omit it will depend on whether `long, multi-line string` may contain regex metacharacters.

Comment: I see now. I think I misunderstood that option, that is why I used it. It will definitely contain regex metacharacters. I'll look into that now. I can see there is an option for setting the newline with -F. Thanks a lot. I'll see how that works.

Comment: Try  `pcregrep -M "\Q$multiline_string\E"` (assuming the multiline string doesn't contain `\E` or use `perl` in slurp mode)

Comment: Related: [How to know if a text file is a subset of another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114877)